# How to fetch data according to my search in a grid

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

In textbox I have to type string which will be searched in a table. if data is found in any of the 3 columns data will be shown in a gridview.3 columns are title, description and keywords. If title chk box is checked it will search through title and if keyword s checked it will search in it. if any of the checkbox is not checked it wont search in tht particular column. I have 2 radio button also one of them need to be selected.if and_radio is clicked it will search data in both columns if or is clicked idf data is found in any of the column will be shown.... Help trying it for a long...It has to be done with procedure.. What code should i have to write on search button click for searching data in textbox and then populate the result in grid
STORED PROCEDURE i used

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

 ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_Normal_Search_Library]

 @title AS nvarchar(max), 
  @Description AS nvarchar(max), 
  @Keywords AS nvarchar(max),
 @Chk_title AS BIT ,
 @Chk_Description AS Bit ,
 @Chk_Keywords AS BIT,
 @RD_AND AS BIT,
 @RD_OR AS BIT


 AS 
if @RD_AND = 1 Begin 
    if @Chk_title = 1       
Begin       
Select title from server_des where title Like '%'+@title+'%' 
End     
if @Chk_Description=1   
    Begin   
    Select Description from server_des where Description  Like '%'+@Description+'%'
        End     
if @Chk_Keywords=1  
    Begin
        Select Keywords from server_des where Keywords Like '%'+@Keywords+'%'
        End     
if @Chk_title = 1 AND @Chk_Description = 1 
        Begin   
    Select title, Description from server_des where title Like '%'+ @title+'%' AND Description  Like '%'+@Description+'%'
        End 
    if @Chk_Description=1 AND @Chk_Keywords=1   
    Begin       
Select Description, Keywords from server_des where  Description  Like'%'+@Description+'%' AND  Keywords Like '%'+@Keywords+'%'  
    End 
    if @Chk_title=1 AND @Chk_Keywords=1
        Begin   
    Select title, Keywords from server_des where title Like'%'+@title+'%' AND Keywords Like'%'+@Keywords+'%'        
End     
if @Chk_title=1 AND @Description=1 AND @title=1     
    Begin       
Select title,Description, Keywords from server_des where title Like '%'+@title+'%'AND Description Like '%'+@Description+'%' AND Keywords Like '%' +@Keywords+'%'
        End     
 End    
ELSE IF @RD_OR=0    
Begin
if @Chk_title = 1   
    Begin       
Select title from server_des where title Like'%'+ @title+'%'    
    End     
if @Chk_Description=1       
Begin       
Select Description from server_des where Description  Like '%'+@Description+'%'
        End     
if @Chk_Keywords=1  
    Begin
        Select Keywords from server_des where Keywords Like '%'+@Keywords+'%'
        End     
if @Chk_title = 1 AND @Chk_Description = 1  
    Begin   
    Select title, Description from server_des where title Like '%'+ @title+'%' AND Description  Like '%'+@Description+'%'
        End     
if @Chk_Description=1 AND @Chk_Keywords=1       
Begin       
Select Description, Keywords from server_des where  Description  Like '%'+@Description+'%' AND  Keywords Like '%'+@Keywords+'%'     
    End 
    if @Chk_title=1 AND @Chk_Keywords=1
        Begin   
    Select title, Keywords from server_des where title Like '%'+@title+'%' AND Keywords Like '%'+@Keywords+'%'  
    End 
    if @Chk_title=1 AND @Description=1 AND @title=1     
    Begin   
    Select title, Description, Keywords from server_des where title Like'%'+@title+'%'AND  Description Like '%'+@Description+'%' AND Keywords Like '%' +@Keywords+'%'
        End 
     End
```

In business logic I created method:

```
 public DataTable Fillgrid(string title,string Description, string Keywords)
    {
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LibrarySql"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "sp_Normal_Search_Library";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    //string query = "select * from Server_des";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description",Description);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Keywords",Keywords);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable  dt = new DataTable();
    con.Open();
    sda.Fill(dt);


    return dt;
```

Now how do I populate data in the grid on my web form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataGrid.DataSource = Fillgrid("title","description","keyword");
DataGrid.Bind();`